# C++ variables scope in multiple files

Tags: c++, scope

How can I make visible variables/functions in particular files?
For example, lets say I have this hierachy of files:

a.h

```
extern int var;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

int var;
```

b.h

```
#include "a.h"

void function();
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

void function() {
    var = 0;
}
```

in main.cpp I want to be able call `function()`, but not to access `var` variable

```
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    function(); /* possible to call */
    var = 0 /* var shouldn't be visible */
}
```

I don't want file a.h to be included in main.cpp - only b.h. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't include `a.h` in `b.h` but include it in `b.cpp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a.h doesn't need to be included in b.h, only b.cpp. This is because `var` is only needed by the function definition, not its declaration. This goes along with the rule not to include headers in other headers unless you absolutely have to.

b.h

```
void function();
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

void function() {
    var = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to stop trying to hide information using the visibility of files, and start looking in to C++ classes which allow you to "hide" things that "methods" use by way of private members:

```
class A
{
private:
    int var;

public:
    void function()
    {
        var = 0;
    };
};
```

Comment: Agree, hiding declarations have weaker privacy guarantees than private members, although both can be cheated if the programmer really wants to.

Comment: @lvella, absolutely agree - but you have to really set out to circumvent a class, whereas accidentally including the wrong file will bring a whole heap of hurt.  Especially as these are globals, without even namespaces to cuddle them by the warm fire with.